# Make a live fifo - bash

Tags: bash, shell, mkfifo

This is the standard piping: `foo | bar`

But I want make a delay between `foo` and `bar`, `foo` output is continues without finish.

I can do `foo > myfile` and n seconds after it start `bar < myfile`. it makes n seconds delay but the big problem is `myfile` gets huge and eats storage for nothing! How can I read from `myfile` and delete read line. something like FIFO.

I tried `mkfifo` but immediately `bar` starts the `foo` jumps out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a third process between the two that sleeps, then starts passing the data along.

```
foo | { sleep 5; cat; } | bar
```

Comment: It did not work. `foo` is a live video and `bar` is streamer. with this command I lost first `n` second of video and it did not buffer the input, just streams from `n` second. Any way to buffer this `n` seconds delay?